# When are Dufour and Soret effects non-negligible?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, transport-phenomena

Dufour effect is often times excluded from energy equations without mentioning. But there are many papers (out of my iq-league) which study effects of these phenomena in chemically reacting flows. Could someone point to me and explain when are these effects negligible and when they are not?

Comment: Soret effect, aka thermophoresis, certainly occurs when an aerosol (liquid or solid) is flowing near a hot or cold solid object, such as a hot wire or a cold wall. It has been known to induce errors in measurement of such cases using hot wire anemometers.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a nearly infinite variety of terms to the energy equation based on what gradients there might be in the situation: concentration gradient $\nabla C$ in the case of mixtures, electric or magentic terms $(\textbf E \times \textbf J)$ in the case of a charged plasma, etc.  So your energy equation can take the form:

$$\frac{DE}{Dt} = \beta \frac{DP}{Dt}  -(\nabla \cdot Q) - (\tau:\nabla \textbf {u})-(\rho \textbf {f}\cdot \textbf{u})-D \nabla C-(\textbf E \times \textbf J) -\dots ^1$$

There is not an absolutely general form that will cover all possible situations.  You have to add source terms to the Right Hand Side as required, and verify that the energy $E$ into takes into account all relevant forms of internal energy in a differential fluid volume, viz.

$$ E = c_pT+\frac{u^2}{2}+(electromagnetic)+(nuclear)+\dots
$$

Maybe that does not address your direct question about Dufour.  This will occur when you have a concentration gradient driving fluids to move against a temperature gradient.

Soret effect, aka thermophoresis, certainly occurs when an aerosol (liquid or solid) is flowing near a hot or cold solid object, such as a hot wire or a cold wall. It has been known to induce errors in measurement of such cases using hot wire anemometers.

$^1 $ terms on the RHS are, in order: compressive heating, heat conduction, viscous heating, work done by body forces, diffusion due to concentration, ohmic resistive heating.